# ng-view not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

Ok, I was trying to create a simple plunkr for a question related to loading times in SPAs with ng-view and it seems I can´t even manage to create a valid scenario.

What I want is a SPA with a ng-view and 2 templates, so every template displays some basic data and can navigate to the other template.

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/krOMYJKw7Eu4282Zn8Ys?p=preview) and this is the code of the spa

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and here is the js

```
angular

.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

.controller('ScreenController', ScreenController)

.config(['$routeProvider', routeProvider])

ScreenController.$inject = [ '$scope' ];

// initial navigation
function routeProvider($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.
  when('/screen1.html', {
    templateUrl: './screen1.html',
    controller: ScreenController
  }).
  when('/screen2.html', {
    templateUrl: './screen2.html',
    controller: ScreenController
  }).
  otherwise({
    url: '/screen1.html',
    templateUrl: './screen1.html',
    controller: ScreenController
  });
}

function ScreenController($scope) {

  $scope.data1 = [];
  $scope.data2 = [];

  $scope.ready = false;

  $scope.numElements = function(scr) {
    var length = scr === '1' ? $scope.data1.length : $scope.data2.length;
    return 'Data has ' + length + ' elements';
  }

  function init() {
    console.info('ScreenController.init');

    $scope.data1 = [
    { a:'a1', b: 'b1' },
    { a:'a2', b: 'b2' },
    { a:'a3', b: 'b3' },
    { a:'a4', b: 'b4' },
    { a:'a5', b: 'b5' },
    { a:'a6', b: 'b6' },
    { a:'a7', b: 'b7' },
    { a:'a8', b: 'b8' }
    ];

    $scope.data2 = [
    { a:'a1', b: 'b1', c:'c1', d:'d1' },
    { a:'a2', b: 'b2', c:'c2', d:'d2' },
    { a:'a3', b: 'b3', c:'c3', d:'d3' },
    { a:'a4', b: 'b4', c:'c4', d:'d4' }
    ];

    console.info('data1: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.data1));
    console.info('data2: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.data2));
    $scope.ready = true;
  }

  init();
}
```

This is not working as I expected.

The first time it loads, the page seems to be working fine as it shows template screen1.html and the data. But once I start clicking the links it doesn´t work anymore, the Controller is not accessed and data is not displayed. Any ideas why?

Many thanks!

Comment: There are multiple issues in this example. Please be more specific, especially with what you expect to happen, since this is not a code review site. Examples could be, why is the list not showing up on page1, or why isn't page1 working when you go back to it from page2?

Comment: You're right @AndréLaszlo, sorry; I edited the post as my question is related to the links not really working as expected.

Comment: numElements() function is expecting some parameter scr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `<a href="#/screen1.html" class="button">To Screen 1</a>` Notice the `#/`. This does not include your other mistakes in your code, like mentioned by others.

Comment: correct, thanks! but any idea why it was loading the template before? shouldn´t that be not working at all?

Comment: @david take a look at my answer below. Dendimiiii is right but I also address some of the other issues in your code. Are you new to Angularjs?

Answer (score 3):

Your screen1.html

```
<div>
  <div>SCREEN1</div>
  <a href="screen2.html" class="button">To Screen 2</a>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="elem in data1">
        <td ng-bind="elem.a"></td>
        <td ng-bind="elem.b"></td>
        <td ng-bind="elem.c"></td>
        <td ng-bind="elem.d"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {{data}} elements
</div>
```

its data1 and not data

Comment: Your code does not reflect the proper solution for the issue. While it does solve one of the many issues, it is not the main issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code should be `<tr ng-repeat="elem in data1">` insted of `<tr ng-repeat="elem in data">`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change a few things.  Set up your ng-view this way. Also with Angularjs it is best practice to keep with angularjs and try not to mix in to much jquery. change your onload to a ng-init, or better yet just load the function in the js controller file once the page has loaded (constructor)

SpaCtrl is your universal controller so you want to us an as statement so it doesnt turn into $scope soup

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="SpaCtrl as spa">
  <ng-view ></ng-view>
</body>
```

Now as for the rest of your code I have split of another plunker for you to see it working. You will notice I changed your js functions to angular functions and it tidied up your html a bit. Let me know if you have any questions!

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lYV7AEYehytpzVksDBrx?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Ohjay44, actually the code is a bit messy, but it's because I just tried to reduce it to the basics. The original code is much more organized. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anytime. One thing to keep in mind is if you have an over arcing controller like your SpaCtrl you want to use an AS statement so you can access it anywhere. I have many SPA that utilize a universal controller. Also it is important to always stick with angularjs once it has started!